# MS Edge HTTP403 from GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl using httpClient.get in aReact WebPart

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am getting a HTTP403 only in MS Edge. I have tested in many other browsers and the .get works fine. I am creating a React WebPart to be used on our SharePoint OnLine environment. The file I am trying to get is a csv file stored in a document library. I am using the web api GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl for the rest call. Here is the snipit:

```
   fileUrl =  "..._api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Shared%20Documents')/Files('file.csv')/$value";
    const csvHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
    csvHeaders.append("Content-type","text/csv");
    csvHeaders.append("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    const csvOpts: IHttpClientOptions = {
      headers: csvHeaders
    };   

this.props.context.httpClient.get(fileUrl,HttpClient.configurations.v1,csvOpts).then((response: HttpClientResponse)=>{ ...
```

Sure hope someone has solved this before. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `spHttpClient` and not `httpClient` in your code.

So, modify your code as `this.props.context.spHttpClient.get(...)` and it should start working.

`spHttpClient` is built specifically to converse with SharePoint REST APIs whereas `httpClient` is built to interact with APIs outside of SharePoint.